# Select N number of rows and UNION the results

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

TABLEA:

```
ConditionId ContentId
10004       101
10004       102
10001       104
10001       103
10001       115
```

From the above data I need to select TOP N records for a particalar ConditionID and merge it with another set of top N results form a different condition id.

For example :
For Condition id 10001 Give out 2 results and Condition ID 10004 give the top 3 results (both of these results should be unique and not overlap):

I Could do :

```
SELECT top(2) * FROM TABLEA
WHERE Conditionid = 10001
UNION 
SELECT top(3) * FROM TABLEA
WHERE Conditionid = 10004
```

But this is just a limited scenario and the condition Ids requested could be multiple instead of just 2 in the above scenario.

I do not want to write a dynamic SQL for performance reasons, is there a way I could do a similar thing by using ConditionId IN()

EDIT:

The results from the top 2 and top 3 should not overlap the contentids, so if a particular contentid was already part of Query 1, it should not be part of the next top N and so on.

Comment: What is the engine version that you're using? Sql Server 2000, 2005, ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: My Edit says "ContentIds" no ConditionIds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way (edited to deal with potential duplicate `Conditionid`).

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
Conditionid INT,
Num INT
)

INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES(10001, 2),
      (10004, 3)


;WITH T(Conditionid, Num) AS
(
SELECT Conditionid,
       MAX(Num)
FROM @T 
GROUP BY Conditionid     
)
SELECT A.*
FROM  T
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (T.Num) *
                FROM   TABLEA A
                WHERE  A.Conditionid = T.Conditionid
                ORDER  BY A.ContentId) A
```

Comment: I've made an EDIT to the question, does this take that into consideration? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Sql-Server 2005 and above:

Note: Top records should be taken after ordering the results

```
declare table @t (numRecords int, id int)
insert into @t (numRecords, id)
values (2, 10001),
       (3, 10004)

;with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over (order by yourOrderCol) rn
   from yourTable
)
select cte.* 
from cte join @t t
     on cte.ConditionId = t.id and cte.rn <= t.numRecords
Order by cte.ConditionId
```

Comment: Will this give distinct results for ContentIds among the multiple Conditionids? Sorry forgot to mention that in the Question, editing now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top(2) * FROM TABLEA
WHERE Conditionid in ('10004', '10005')
UNION 
SELECT top(3) * FROM TABLEA
WHERE Conditionid = ('10004', '10006')
```

is this what you expected

Comment: That will do, but it does not cater for the dynamic aspect of multiple conditions as mentioned above.